# Eclipse : Add new character on "Matching brackets highlight" functionality

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse : 3.6.2 (Java Perspective / *.java file)

Hi everybody,

Is there an easy way to add some new character ( like "<",">") on eclipse "Matching brackets highlight" functionality ?

Currently eclipse works fine with : () - {} - []

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java Editor already matches '<' and '>' while working with Java 5 source.

In general this is not configurable, some code has to be changed to match new characters. Now which additional characters you want to match? In which editor?

Comment: Currently I can't matches '<' and '>' like '(' and ')' (I'm on Java Perspective / *.java file). For example : //<foo> and (foo) #here when I clicked on a brace, the other brace is selected, but when I clicked on a '<' the other one isn't selected.

Comment: It doesn't do matching within comments.   How frequently is it needed?

Comment: Starting 3.8 M6 it works in comments as well :-) There was a bug which has been fixed...